# How do I add methods and attributes using ObjectAid?

Tags: java, objectaid

My goal is to add methods and attributes to the class diagram to make it generate stubs of code in the classes.

Here's an example:

If I'm just starting a project. I have a class called `tuna` and I want to add the methods `swim()`, `eat()` and `poop()` with it generating stubs. This way by the time I'm done with all the classes and start to code I won't forget what I was thinking.

Could ObjectAid be the wrong tool for the job?

Comment: did you check here http://www.objectaid.com/class-diagram

Comment: You'll need to give us more to assist. What have you tried? What were the results? Speaking form experience if you've been mashing at this for hours without much success you'll probably be better off walking away (having a sleep) and coming back to it fresh.

Comment: @GanGnaMStYleOverFlowErroR yeah, I looked there but that seems to be all on reverse engineering and linking classes.

Answer (score 1):

ObjectAid can only show you the source code, you have to go to an editor to change it. When you double-click on a class, method or field, an editor will open at the proper location.